# how I can login with facebook or something else, after that i integrate with google account to get the service of google

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

Because when integrate with google account the auth user set into google account but i wan't the information of authentication i have made before

hope everyone to give me solution

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Since you're using java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. here's the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).